# Reuse an expression from one IQueryable<T> on another IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Is it possible to take an `Expression` created on one `IQueryable<T>` and apply or execute it on another `IQueryable<T>`.

Below is a simple test to show the expected result, but the actual result is that nothing (empty) is returned.  I have made sure that the types are identical.

Maybe there is another way to destruct and recreate the expression?

**Test**

```
[Test]
    public void CreateQuerySimple_GivenExpression_ShouldGenerateReport()
    {
      // arrange
      var emptyList = new List<OutputChannelLogTest>().AsQueryable();
      var query = emptyList.Where(x => x.Channel == "Channel2");
      var expression = query.Expression;
      
      Console.WriteLine(@$"Expression: {expression}");

      
      var dbItems = new List<OutputChannelLogTest>
      {
        new OutputChannelLogTest(){Channel = "Channel1", CreatedBy = "createdBy1"},
        new OutputChannelLogTest(){Channel = "Channel1", CreatedBy = "createdBy2"},
        new OutputChannelLogTest(){Channel = "Channel2", CreatedBy = "createdBy3"},
        new OutputChannelLogTest(){Channel = "Channel2", CreatedBy = "createdBy4"},
      };
      var dbQuery = dbItems.AsQueryable();

      // action
      var reportItems = dbQuery.Provider.CreateQuery<OutputChannelLogTest>(expression);

      // assert
      reportItems.Count().Should().Be(2);
    }
```

**Simple Type**

```
public class OutputChannelLogTest
  {
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Channel { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? this expression is MethodCallExpression ... and first argument of it is previous list ...

Comment: I have @Selvin, but because both types are identical I assumed I can transfer / reuse it.  My issue is that I have no idea what expression will be created on the first IQueryable.  I need to take what was created and pass it to the next.

Comment: Would `Expression<Func<OutputChannelLogTest, bool>> predicate = x => x.Channel == "Channel2";` suit your needs? then you can use `var filtered = someOtherSource.Where(predicate)` later - that do?

Comment: The use case is:  We have HotChockolate GraphQL with custom middleware, the middleware traps the IQueryable just before sending the result back to the caller.  The expression on the IQueryable is then captured and its expression passed to the report engine.  Passing the IQueryable is not an option, the backing source is different.

Comment: [Very, very, very hacky way...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZYWvTo) using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core package ... not sure if those would work with all queries

Comment: I am going to try you solution.  Assuming it will handle something like this that will also happen in the pipeline.  `query = query.Where(x=>x.CreatedBy==_getLoggedOnUser())`

Comment: I don't think if this would work as there is no context to call `_getLoggedOnUser()` method

Comment: in non static you have to replace in expression "value(ClassName)"  to somthing like "thizz" and then add `{ "thizz", this}` to dictionary

Comment: @Selvin `_getLoggedOnUser()` is just an illustration where dependency injection ensures that the repose filters records that are only for the logged in user.  The actual implementation works and does exactly that.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lv7z2B if there is some other instance call then things started getting even more messy

Comment: @Selvin - A colleage pointed me to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670650/how-to-apply-an-expression-tree-for-iqueryable

See - https://dotnetfiddle.net/SncK6W  I think this is the answer.  Do I delete this question?

Comment: I would rather recommend writing an answer  instead of deleting the question

Comment: This shows a simulated pipeline and it works 100%  - https://dotnetfiddle.net/FoQc72

Comment: Nice finding... And what about method calls?

Comment: I will start with this and then build on it if necessary